# Android Studio not connecting to internet and get 403 response

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-sdk-tools

When installing Android Studio the action **Finding available SDK components** seems failed and no SDK get installed.

Also tried to install SDK using Android commond line tools and when I try to get list of SDKs by using below command

**sdkmanager --list --verbose** I get 403 error for downloading below xml file
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml,https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml,https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml

But when I try from browser I am able to download those files.I am using my office laptop and I have checked **Automatically detect settings** in LAN settings and even I tried with uncheck that option also ,still getting the same result.

When I try to connect the Office VPN and set the proxy then I am not able to download by browser also

I tried with change setting in "No Proxy", "Auto Detect" and "Http Proxy" options in android studio also still no luck

And when I start Android Studio it shows "Untrusted Server's certificate" for "*.google.com" and I click Accept to continue.

I am using Windows 10 and AdoptOpenJDK 11. How I can resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance